# Equivalent terminal command to launcher icon

Tags: terminal

How can I find the equivalent terminal command of some program I started from the GUI? For example, I open the start menu, go to accessories, and start the image viewer. Is there a way to find the equivalent terminal command for that action?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right click the menu entry, select properties.

[image]

Select the Desktop Entry tab, command shows the terminal command, in this case 'gpicview'.

[image]

Comment: Nice succinct answer but can I suggest you clarify that, from this example, the `%f` is not part of the command that you might try running on the terminal but rather expanded to a filename by the menu entry. Other options are listed here https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en#commandline